# How can I create a new planet/satellite system that generates tides of 6-8 metres?

Tags: science-based, planets, tides, satellites

I'm creating a new setting for a novel. I'd like to build a world where the interaction between the planet and its satellite/satellites can generate a normal tide excursion around 6/8 metres. Furthermore I need that once every 500 years there occurs a low tide ten/twenty times that of the normal ones.

Can anyone suggest to me how to set up this relationship to be at least credible?

I'm thinking of a system with a central planet with 2 satellites, where the nearest is smaller and orbits faster, and a second one is bigger and farther away with a really slow orbit with a very elliptical path, but I don't know if this solution can work.

P.S.: Obviously the number is merely indicative only for give you an idea of how this thing should work.

Comment: Just for reference - Wikipedia's [tidal range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidal_range) article states: "Coastal tidal ranges vary globally and can differ anywhere from near zero to over 38 feet (12 metres)" and "The world's largest tidal range of 16.3 metres (53.5 feet) occurs in Bay of Fundy, Canada, and the United Kingdom regularly experiences tidal ranges up to 15 metres (49 feet) between England and Wales in the Severn Estuary.". The map from that same article seems to indicate that most of Earth's oceans and coastal areas don't experience more than 0.60 meter (less than 2 feet) tides.

Comment: thanks for your reference. yes i know that there's many place on the heart with such tidal range but when i think 6/8 metres i'm referring to a medium tide on the costal area as wel as the 0.60 cm indicated. But with this reference i can think on a 1/10 ration and then the distance between the panet and the first satellite can be 1/10 of the distance between heart and the moon

Comment: You may consider that not actually gravity, but possibly geographical structures are the determining factor for the average height of tidal waves. This way you can keep your moon similar to earth and only adapt your coast lines.

Comment: Good point i never think on this. sorry for my ignorance wich kind of geofical structures can generate a similar effect?

Comment: @Krokhmir if you put your satellite at 1/10th of the distance that the Moon is from the Earth, the tides will be a _thousand_ times as big. Tidal force varies with the inverse cube of distance.

Comment: you're saing that i must reduce the distance only of 1/1000 of 384.000 km, im right?

Comment: A low tide in one location requires a high tide elsewhere.  This means your 500 year low 80-160m low tide will have a coastal-flooding-capable 80-160m high tide somewhere else.  Are you OK with that?  Also, please note that you can send a notification to a user that you're responding to their comment by placing a "@" before their username.  So, to tell me you're responding to my comment you'd include @JBH somewhere in your comment.

Comment: @JBH Another good point, my story is incentrate only on this part of the world but the consequence of this may be wider. The high tide isn't a problem by itself for the story but i can consider some migration from other location, thanks

Comment: Let me give you one more insight: Let's assume that we create the effect by using two moons: one like Earth's and one, 10X bigger, in a huge 500 year elliptical orbit.  Your worst-case tides (what you're looking for) occur when that 2nd moon is closest to your planet ... but the planet will feel the changes as the moon approaches and leaves.  For 125 years you'll have increasingly bad tides until the worst then 125 more years of weakening tides then 250 years of "normal" tides.

Comment: @Krokhmir No, I’m saying that you must reduce the distance by dividing by the cube root of ten, not by dividing by ten.

Comment: @JBH You can’t have a satellite of a habitable planet with a 500-year orbit; it will be way, way outside the planet’s Hill sphere.

Comment: @mike scott thank you sometimes i lost something with english

Comment: @jhb and what if we speack of the satellite instead of planet, somethin like jupiter and Europa, in your opinion? We can have an interation between our satellite (named A) onother one (named B) and the planet. Sure probably i must reduce the time for the lower tide but....

Comment: As you listen to all our comments, you'll discover a lot of facts.  I'm not an astrophysicist, so it was cool to hear from @MikeScott about the Hill sphere.  However, you're writing a story and your goal is suspension of disbelief, not necessarily scientific purity.  One out of 100,000 people who read your story might know about the Hill sphere - and they'll ignore the issue if you tell a good story.  Think about the entire Marvel Cinematic Universe - very little of what you see is scientifically plausible (most isn't even possible), but we enjoy it anyway.

Comment: @JBH lol you're right. surerly this was an interesting discusion, i will cosider all of your point while writing. thanks a lot

Answer (score 5):

Tides are nothing but waves on the ocean, which are driven by the moon's and sun's gravitation. And, as with any wave, absolute hight depends *heavily* on resonances.

A commenter has already given the location on earth with the highest tides, which is a *bay* (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bay_of_Fundy). I.e. a half enclosed region of just the right size to produce such a strong resonance that you get 16m high tides. Most of the remaining water surfaces are not as highly resonant with the fixed frequency of gravity change, so you only get small tides that mostly don't exceed 1m.

So, you have two routes to go:

1. You heavily increase the tidal forces. I.e. bigger moon that's closer by.
2. You heavily increase the resonances. If you have a shoreline that's for some weird reason a sequence of bays like the Bay of Fundy, you get the high tides in each of those bays. You'll also get low tides at the coasts that are directly facing the open ocean.

   If you go this route, you can use bays of virtually any size, as long as you adjust the length of the day accordingly. The larger the bays, the longer the day needs to be.

In either case, be aware though that those large tides won't last for long (= long in the geographical sense): The higher the tides, the faster the energy transfer from the earth's rotation to the moon's orbit and water heat content. So, the higher the tides, the faster the earth's rotation looses speed. And as your days get longer (very gradually, but I'm speaking about geological timespans here), the bays will get out of resonance and loose their high-tide property.

Answer (score 4):

**This has probably already happened to the Earth.**

It is generally believed that the moon was formed from an impact event between a very young earth and a planet around the same size as Mars. In point of fact, it has been postulated that the young moon was responsible for the [creation of life](https://www.newscientist.com/article/dn4786-no-moon-no-life-on-earth-suggests-theory/) on earth, and that when it was newly formed from the debris ring around the earth, it was much closer to the earth, orbiting the earth every 6 hours or so and causing a massive tidal effect.

Ultimately, the closer you bring the moon to the Earth and the closer in relative size they are, the larger your tidal forces. The sun is also a factor though, so if you move the earth even slightly closer to the sun, and have a moon up close, you can end up with massive king tides as a result of alignment between sun and moon.

Mind you, the closer you put the Earth to the sun, the less time the earth will be in a habitable range (the sun is slowly heating up and in billions of years, Mars will actually be in the goldilocks zone, not earth) and having the moon closer, while potentially necessary for the *establishment* of life, may make the earth far less comfortable for the *sustainment* of life depending on what you're trying to achieve.

If the only thing you care about are tidal forces, then these configurations will help you. If you want this planet to harbour life to the point of intelligence, it may be a little more problematic. In any event, just move your moon closer to the earth and you get reasonable tidal variations quite quickly. You don't even have to move it much to have a great effect because of the squared effect of proximity on gravitational pull.

In other words, move it to half its current distance from the Earth, and your tidal forces quadruple. Move it to around a third of the current distance, and you have nearly 10 times the tidal forces in play. Of course, in both cases, your tides move much faster between high and low tides (unless you greatly slow down the rotation of the earth) so the impact on life is going to be greater than simple difference in tide height; you're generating a massive amount of momentum as well which brings its own problems that will have to be dealt with by life struggling to survive on the surface.

Answer (score 0):

**Horseshoe Orbits**

Yes, long term (geological timescales) stability will be an issue with this setup but it should be the setup that most closely matches your criteria.

Start with Earth's horseshoe orbit relationship with [Cruithne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3753_Cruithne), which is on about a 770 year cycle.  This concept is easily modified to more closely match your 500 time requirement.  From there, replace Cruithne with your tide "planet" and replace Earth with a large Gas Giant planet.  When the Gas Giant approaches your tide planet, once every 500 years or so, the tides get huge for a significant time (probably several years, though I don't know how to do the math on it), before the tide planet and gas giant separate again for the next 500 years.